# GeoServer crash after restart

Tags: geoserver

I have some big problem. I can't open GeoServer after restart the system. It shows `HTTP ERROR: 503`

Problem accessing `/geoserver/web/`. Reason:

```
Service Unavailable

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'DiskQuotaMonitor' defined in URL [jar:file:/D:/GeoServer%202.9.1/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-gwc-2.9.1.jar!/geowebcache-diskquota-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not locate a layer or layer group with id LayerGroupInfoImpl--39f2944:15948bbab19:-8000 within GeoServer configuration, the GWC configuration seems to be out of synch
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    ... 66 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not locate a layer or layer group with id LayerGroupInfoImpl--39f2944:15948bbab19:-8000 within GeoServer configuration, the GWC configuration seems to be out of synch
    at org.geoserver.gwc.layer.GeoServerTileLayer.getPublishedInfo(GeoServerTileLayer.java:313)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.layer.GeoServerTileLayer.getLayerInfo(GeoServerTileLayer.java:292)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.layer.GeoServerTileLayer.getLatLonBbox(GeoServerTileLayer.java:256)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.layer.GeoServerTileLayer.checkGridSubsets(GeoServerTileLayer.java:783)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.layer.GeoServerTileLayer.getGridSubsets(GeoServerTileLayer.java:771)
    at org.geowebcache.diskquota.LayerCacheInfoBuilder.findOnDiskTileSets(LayerCacheInfoBuilder.java:148)
    at org.geowebcache.diskquota.LayerCacheInfoBuilder.buildCacheInfo(LayerCacheInfoBuilder.java:110)
    at org.geowebcache.diskquota.DiskQuotaMonitor.launchCacheInfoGatheringThreads(DiskQuotaMonitor.java:413)
    at org.geowebcache.diskquota.DiskQuotaMonitor.startUpInternal(DiskQuotaMonitor.java:272)
    at org.geowebcache.diskquota.DiskQuotaMonitor.startUp(DiskQuotaMonitor.java:231)
    at org.geowebcache.diskquota.DiskQuotaMonitor.afterPropertiesSet(DiskQuotaMonitor.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    ... 73 more
```

Comment: You've likely made some change (perhaps manual edit of the data directory, or running GWC without geoserver), and you need to undo it. There is more logging after this, and the detail matters.